# Ruby on Rails: Confused about how link_to parameters for a delete action with a 'do' block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a web app where a user can create and delete his own events. I am trying to link to a delete action when a user presses on a 'trashcan' icon (a font awesome icon) but am a bit stuck. I need to include the icon inside a link_to "do" block since I want the user to press it to delete his own event.

This is easy to do for a GET route, since I can just link to that view, for example, the code to edit a user's event looks like (I am using the cancan gem for authentication):

```
<% if can? :update, @event %>
  <%= link_to edit_event_path(@event), class: 'user' do %>
    <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
        title="Edit your event" class="custom-a2">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x">&nbsp;</i>
    </i>
   <% end %>
```

The above works. And the previous working link_to code to delete an event is:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

So the above also works, but I want it so that when the user presses on a trashcan icon, it would link to the delete action of the events controller. This is confusing because this isn't a GET request, and so I need to pass the specific user and event to a link_to action without actually redirecting the user to a view. Can I please get help? My attempt is as below:

```
<%= link_to(@event), controller: :events, action: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'user' do %>
  <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
      title="Delete your event" class="custom-a2">
    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x">&nbsp;</i>
  </i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to send the event to the delete action for deleting purpose. this should work:

```
   <%= link_to @event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'user' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Gives me a syntax error, something about expecting end of input, I think there are too many comas in your solution, but I also tried something like that before.

Comment: sorry for that. let me know i will update my answer as well. :)